# MySQL/ORACLE performance using LIKE and CONCAT

Tags: mysql, oracle, performance

Which one of these two queries would perform better in MySQL and/or ORACLE?

```
SELECT * 
FROM User 
WHERE name LIKE "%searchTerm%"
OR lastname LIKE "%searchTerm%" 
OR email LIKE "%searchTerm%";
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM User 
WHERE CONCAT(name, " ", lastname, " ", email) LIKE "%searchTerm%";
```

I have a strong feeling that the second one, but I'd like to be sure.

Comment: What do you get with `Explain` ?

Comment: It's likely both of them will do a Full Table Scan, so there probably isn't much difference between them. In Oracle you could build a Function-Based Index on concatenated columns, which might get you a Full Fast Scan of the index instead.  .

Comment: Examples have no valid syntax for Oracle. Single quotes must be used and [`CONCAT`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions040.htm#SQLRF00619) has only two parameters and must be nested or `||` should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the two queries are **not equivalent**. In case that a blank (the concatenation delimiter) may be used in the *searchTerm*, the first query may not match, but the second can, because the match  spans two or three columns.

Performance will be very same as both queries make full table scan and the difference is only in the *filter condition*

**First Query**

```
   1 - filter("NAME" IS NOT NULL AND "NAME" IS NOT NULL AND "NAME" LIKE 
              '%searchTerm%' OR "LASTNAME" IS NOT NULL AND "LASTNAME" IS NOT NULL AND 
              "LASTNAME" LIKE '%searchTerm%' OR "EMAIL" IS NOT NULL AND "EMAIL" IS 
              NOT NULL AND "EMAIL" LIKE '%searchTerm%')
```

**Second Query**

```
  1 - filter("NAME"||' '||"LASTNAME"||' '||"EMAIL" LIKE '%searchTerm%')
```

So basically **neither query is suitable for a customer search on non trival tables**.

You typically want to limit the search to `column LIKE 'xxxxxx%'` which can use an index.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM User 
WHERE name LIKE "%searchTerm%"
OR lastname LIKE "%searchTerm%" 
OR email LIKE "%searchTerm%";
```

This query is **better** then second one. Because if you want to use **different filter** on all the Fields then you can use them easily.

```
SELECT * 
FROM User 
WHERE CONCAT(name, " ", lastname, " ", email) LIKE "%searchTerm%";
```

In this query you can not use different filter. **You have to use common filter on all the fields.**

Answer (score 0):

(MySQL Answer)

Either way will involve a full table scan, so neither will be fast.  (Fetching rows is more costly than evaluating expressions.)  Furthermore, the *leading* wildcard implies that the string(s) must be fully scanned; no `INDEX` usable possible.

If your "serachTerm" is always word(s), then use `FULLTEXT(name, lastname, email)` and `MATCH(name, lastname, email) AGAINST ("+searchTerm" IN BOOLEAN MODE)`; it will be a *lot* faster.